# Can't receive Firebase Notifications on emulator behind proxy

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, android-emulator, apk

I can't receive firebase notifications on emulator behind proxy

But if I install the apk on an android device and then send a notification it is received.

> I am using API 27 x86 image emulator.
>
> App is compiled against API 27 with Target as well 27.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You indicate the emulator image is API 27.  Is the non-emulator device API 27 also?

Comment: No. the non emulator device is API 21.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building your app with version 11.8.0 of the Firebase SDK, the problem is likely caused by the emulator image not having a compatible version of Google Play services.  The latest API 27 emulator image does not support 11.8.0

Look in the logcat at the time the app initializes for this warning: `W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date`.  If you see that, the simplest option is to run with an API 26 emulator image, which supports 11.8.0.

The FCM [setup instructions in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-play) explain that apps built with Firebase should check for a compatible version of Google Play services.